# Efficiently Identify and return missing values in large worksheet

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have a large sheet (**Parts**) of 700.000+ lines with parts that belong to a machine with a unique ID.

```
ID  |  Part  | Final Category  |  Part Cost Price
```

In another sheet (**Machine cost price**) I have a list with machine IDs that I want to check on completeness (to make sure I am not missing anything/nothing goes wrong).

```
ID  |  Total costs
```

How can I efficiently check if I have included all IDs from sheet 'Parts' in the 'Machine Cost Price' sheet - and if i miss one add it to the bottom?

I already tried a foreach loop, however that caused my excel to crash instantly.

Any help would be appriciated:)

Comment: Can't you just do a VLOOKUP on the "Machine cost price" sheet?

Comment: Or a `=IF(COUNTIF('Machine Cost Price'!A1,'Parts'!A1:A700000)>0,"In Parts List", "Not in Parts List")`

Comment: What I understand is you need the sum of the prices of all parts. If the prices/rows for each ID are available, you could create a pivot table if that suits your process. If you want it all to be programmatically checked, you could write a few simple loops. Please post the code you've written so far and the community will provide suggestions. Do identify where specifically you're facing challenges.

Comment: @Jnevill and DavyC, that would indeed be a good suggestion if I only need to check it a  Machine is in the parts list. However as both sheets come from different sources it could also be that I have parts but no machines. In that case I would like to know which machine IDs these parts belong to and add them to the Machine Cost Price sheet.

Comment: @MikeC, thanks for your suggestion, i just need to check it all machine IDs mentioned in the Parts sheet are also in the Machine Cost Price sheet. For this I could use a pivot table and an if loop indeed, however I try to prevent adding a sheet. Do you have an idea on how to do it without adding an sheet (and prefetably without adding columns too)?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far and the community will provide suggestions. Do identify where specifically you're facing challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requirement is multipart:

1. Check the machine list to insure all machines are represented in parts list
2. Check the parts list to insure all machines are represented in machine list

The first part can be easily solved with a sheet formula, so I'll focus on the second one where a `for each` loop will get out of hand.

To solve, I would:

Copy the list of 700000 machines to a new tab:

```
Sheets("Parts").Range("A1:A700000").copy Destination:=Sheets("newtab").range("A1")
```

Dedup the list using excels built in `.RemoveDuplicates` method of the `Range` object:

```
Sheets("newTab").Range("A1:A700000").RemoveDuplicates(1,xlNo)
```

Now you can `For Each` this much smaller range or you can toss a formula in there.

```
Dim machineCell As Range

'Loop through each cell in the dedup range
For Each machineCell In Sheets("newtab").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("newtab").Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row()).Cells

    'using the .find method of the range object, check for the machine value in the machine worksheet
    Set test = Range("A1:A5").Find(machineCell.Value)
    If Not test Is Nothing Then
        'If test is a range that is set, then we found it.
        'So update the column next to our machine cell to "found"
        machineCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "found"
    End If
Next machineCell
```

Comment: I think this will be a really helpfull solution. Just let me check one more time; you do advise me to either add a column to a sheet or have a new sheet for the fist part? I.E.i cannot efficiently do this without adding one?

Comment: Yes, because the Machine Id in the Parts sheet needs to be deduped to efficiently check each id against the Machine list. You could also query the sheet as if it were a database with something like `SELECT [Parts].* FROM [Parts] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Machines] on [Parts].Machineid = [Machines].Id WHERE [Machines].Id IS NULL`, but you'd have to set up a connection through ADO, with the Jet or Ace ODBC adapter to a saved copy of the sheet, in VBA to pull it off and given the steep learning curve I would just dedup and `countif()`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a bridge too far indeed. Thanks for the great help!:)